# Bash insert content into n th html tag

Tags: shell, sed

My `Template.html` contains two `<pre>` tags to which content from two different files needs to be inserted. The following inserts file content for all matches. How to insert only into 1st or 2nd `<pre>` tag?

```
sed -i -e '/<pre>/r file1.txt' Template.html
```

`Template.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>
<pre>
</pre>
<div>
<pre>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

file1.txt

```
  hello
  world
```

file2.txt

```
  may
  june
```

Expected Result:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>
    <pre>
    hello
    world
    </pre>
    <div>
    <pre>
    may
    june
    </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure if I get it, where is the question in this post? Please be more clear in your question.

Comment: Updated with clarity.

Comment: You posted sample input but forgot to post the expected output. See [ask] and in particular the part about creating a [mcve]

Comment: @itsraja: The question has nothing to do with `bash` tag. Why do you keeping adding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is for doing simple s/old/new, **that is all**. It sounds like what you want would be something like this (set tgt to 1 or 2 or whichever `<pre>` you want the block to be inserted after):

```
awk -v tgt=1 '
NR==FNR { rec = rec $0 ORS; next }
{ print }
/<pre>/ && (++cnt == tgt) { printf "%s", rec }
' file1.txt Template.html
```

but with neither an example of `file1.txt` nor the expected output it's just an untested guess.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/<pre>/{x;s/^/x/;/^x\{1\}$/{x;r file1.txt' -e 'x};x}' Template.html
```

On encountering a line with the required tag, increment a counter in the hold space.

If the counter matches the required number (in this case 1) append the text file.

Thus the following will append the file after the third occurrence of the tag.

```
 sed -e '/<pre>/{x;s/^/x/;/^x\{3\}$/{x;r file1.txt' -e 'x};x}' Template.html
```